# Error during insert the XML file content into an access database

Tags: asp.net, database, vb.net, insert

in a web application, i want to insert the XML file content into an access database, i got the code (below), but there is an error with this line

```
 xmlFile = XmlReader.Create("Product.xml", New XmlReaderSettings())
```

this error appear

[image]

please take a look at the code below and tell me how to modify to get the "product.xml" from the web application root folder. i tried "~/product.xml" and it did not work

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Xml

Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Data

Public Class Form1

    Public Shared Sub mimi()

    Dim connetionString As String

    Dim connection As OleDbConnection

    Dim command As OleDbCommand

    Dim ds As New DataSet

    Dim xmlFile As XmlReader

    Dim sql As String
    Dim adpter As New OleDbDataAdapter




    Dim product_ID As Integer

    Dim Product_Name As String

    Dim product_Price As Double



    connetionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= |datadirectory|CRF.mdb;Persist Security Info=True"

    connection = New OleDbConnection(connetionString)



    xmlFile = XmlReader.Create("Product.xml", New XmlReaderSettings())

    ds.ReadXml(xmlFile)

    Dim i As Integer

    connection.Open()

    For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1

        product_ID = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(0))

        Product_Name = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(1)

        product_Price = Convert.ToDouble(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(2))

        sql = "insert into Product values(" & product_ID & ",'" & Product_Name & "'," & product_Price & ")"

        command = New OleDbCommand(sql, connection)

        adpter.InsertCommand = command

        adpter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Next

    connection.Close()

End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Product.xml")